# Flexbox searchbar over flexbox buttons

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

the goal is to somewhat recreate google's search bar. What i've got so far:

```
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="positions.css">
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="input_field">
        <input type="text" name="q">
    </div>
    <form action="https://google.com/search">
        <div class="flexbox-container">                
            <div class="button_search_pos"><input type="submit" value="Google Search"></div>
            <div class="lucky_pos"><input type="submit" value="I’m Feeling Lucky"></div>     
        </div>
```

And the .css to that:

I tried several tips of other solved issues on Stackoverflow, but they didn't seem to work. Found some vids on youtube with already finished forms like this, but thats not my way of doing things. How do i center the input over both buttons from the Flexbox? The input must be "flexible" so that when the page shrinks, it wraps accordingly to other elements.

Thanks in advance!

````
#input_field{
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    left: 41%;
}
.flexbox-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.lucky_pos, .button_search_pos{    
    text-align: center;
    padding:1px;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
}```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SfuF.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS code, i edited your's

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#input_field{
  
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10%
}
.flexbox-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;    
   margin-top: 5%;
}
.lucky_pos, .button_search_pos{    
    text-align: center;
    padding:1px;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: It turned them further away from each other.

Comment: this is the result for css i have attached https://ibb.co/VWzLgRV

Comment: Can you provide me with a screenshot for the result you had after applying my CSS edits ?

Comment: increased the margin on the input. Im happy now! Thank you.